# Moving equation when saved

Tags: r, ggplot2, save, equation, stat

I have been using the command ggsave to save my plots:

```
ggsave("t1_b_radish.jpg")
```

But when i save it, the equations in plot moves at random spot.
I have a lot of plots to save, so saving by export is not an option (also it ruins the quality).
Is there any simpler way to make it not not move my equations?
This is what i am using to create equation:

```
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),
               formula = formula, geom = "text", hjust=0.2,vjust=30, parse = TRUE, size = 3)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This helps us to recreate your problem and give you better answers.

Comment: I think your label is moving because you are using an extreme value for `vjust`. You should not use `vjust` or `hjust` to move your text large distances, since they depend on the size of the plotting device and the font used. You should instead specify the y value where you want the text to appear via the aesthetic mapping. It's impossible to give you any more specific advice without a reproducible example though

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I Saved them just keeping the height and width ratio same and adding DPI value as high for better quality. IT worked perfectly while still making it easy to save multiple plots quickly.